# Created Group folder is not visible in show in finder on xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am working on an `iphone` app and i created different group folders like `Json` ,`Asi` etc .

In **Xcode** its easy to classify the file in this way , but when i am trying to show in finder all the files are comes under the main project .

Is there any way to make grouped folder visible and also to show in finder?

I tried to create folders manually but it is also not working .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You have to track (create) the folders both in xocde and in finder manually.

You can create folder in finder and then can import that folder in xcode.

The folder you make in xcode is identical to the finder.

So, the folder that you will make in finder, will be the original tree structure for your project.

Answer (score 2):

you have to physically create your folders first in order to find that folder in finder. do following steps :

- Go to Project Folder.
- Create new folder.
- Go to opened project in xcode. Right click on project folder visible in left panel.
- Add Files to "your project Name".
- Select your folder and uncheck copy items to destination'folder
- Done.

Thanks,

Comment: you need to create folders physically not from Xcode. you have to reach the destination project folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a folder or group in X-Code it does not actually create physical folder in the file system of your MAC instead it manages a group with in the x-code project file with files you added to that group.In other words as mentioned in the above answers you need to create the physical folder in projects root directory and add to x-code to get the behavior you are looking for.